# What is the main difference between these two ids?

Tags: css, css-selectors

What is the difference between these two ids? 

 `p#id1 { code goes here }`  and  
`#id1 p { code goes here }`

Comment: First one is multiple element selector which selects the paragraph with that id. Second one is descendant selector which selects the paragraph inside the element with that id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `p#id1` will select `<p id="id1">`
2. `#id1 p` will select `<div id="#id1"><p></p></div>` Inner `p` element

So both is selecting `p` element but different `p` element:

**First**: `p#id1` Will select `p` having ID `id1` because there is no space between them.

**Second**: Will select child `p` element of ID `id1`

See it in action:

```css
p#id1{ color: red;}
#id1 p{ color: green;}
```

```html
<p id="id1">I am with having id id1</p>
<div id="id1"><p>I am child element</p></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

**`p#id1 { code goes here }`** This will target any `p` tag with `id="id1"`

```
<p id="id1"></p>
```

and

**`#id1 p { code goes here }`** This will target `p` tag inside `id="id1"`

```
<div id="id1"> <p> </p> </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**p#id1** will select all the p tag in page having ID specified ie.`<p id="id1">`

**#id1** p will select the p as child element of ID specified ie.`<div id="#id1"><p>  </p></div>`

Answer (score 0):

1. Writing `#id1 p`  you are selecting `p` element which are  inside of `#id1`
2. Writing `p#id1` you are selecting `p` tag with id `#id1` but **since id's are unique you don't need to specify it with tag** in this case you can write as simple as `#id1{ your style }`.